# Does Windows 2003 support TLS 1.1 and 1.2?

Tags: tls, windows

Does windows 2003 support TLS 1.1 and 1.2. 
The server need to consume the service hosted on other server, using https with TLS 1.1 and 1.2 certificate.

Comment: Do you mean a situation in which some service or application running on Windows 2003 connects to a webserver (or other service) with TLS?

Comment: The _certificate_ is unrelated to the protocol; the same cert can be used for all of SSL3 and TLS 1.0 1.1 1.2 (though of course you _shouldn't_ use SSL3). However, _other_ things in the cert (or chain) may matter; in particular S2003 needed a hotfix for RSA-with-SHA2 signatures which all public CAs have been using for at least a year. (XP got the same fix in SP2).  Also some modern servers want SNI which is technically independent of protocol but was mostly implemented at the same _time_ as 1.1; IIRC both S2003 _and_ XP didn't do SNI.

Comment: @techraf yes, it is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not supported natively. Support for TLS 1.1 and 1.2 was added to Windows Server 2008 R2.

See [How to restrict the use of certain cryptographic algorithms and protocols in Schannel.dll](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245030).

Neither IIS provided with Windows 2003 nor Internet Explorer versions 7 and 8 (executable on Windows 2003) support TLS 1.1/TLS 1.2.

If the application uses the library provided by operating system (`schannel.dll`), then Windows 2003 supports only: SSL 2.0, SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0.

However if the application used/implemented another library, it might support the versions in question ([for example](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000220586&language=en_US) Chrome and Firefox browsers support TLS 1.1 and 1.2 when running on older Windows systems as well).